# Copy with Finder from external HDD to MacHDD(data) fails with zero byte entry and no warnings or copy dialogue

Tags: finder, catalina, ntfs, hdd

I have an old NTFS backup disk (simple copy) used 2007-2014. Disk File system is OK.  I can open the files (Canon raw images) from the HDD using applications on the Mac so the Mac talks to the HDD.

Copy files with Finder to the Mac HDD fails silently. No copy dialogue - filenames appear in destination folder initially showing file-sizes but they are zero byte.

I can copy these same files with Finder from the external HDD to an attached Pen Drive and then copy from the Pen Drive to the Mac HDD but I cannot copy directly from the external HDD to the Mac hard drive.

I am using an up-to-date Catalina and up-to-date Paragon NTFS - but that should not be needed to read NTFS. Machine is a late 2012 iMac. Tried multiple remounts (physical disconnection) HDD and restarted iMac.

In hours of searching I have only found one near identical report of this behaviour - on here asked March 28 2013.

My workaround using a second connected disk and copying twice works but I am mystified. No permission errors. As well as running Time Machine I have always kept a manual backup of my photos to an external HDD. I use NTFS and Paragon because I was using a PC before I switched to Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been experiencing the same issue you're describing here and have a couple of workarounds that might be useful.

### Option 1

Use the command line, the `cp` command seems to copy the files over just fine.

### Option 2

Mount the drive in read-only mode. This is an option within the paragon `NTFS for Mac` application. After you've connected the drive and it shows up in the application you can opt to mount it in read-only mode.

You will have to re-mount the drive after for the change to take effect, this can be easily done using the unmount and mount buttons in the app. You won't, of course, be able to make any changes to any of the files in this mode.